# Making subqueries on eloquent LARAVEL 5.2.29

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, subquery

I am trying to exclude a few records from a select that has a null column in its relationship.

**This is the query I hope to achieve:**

```
SELECT 
FROM modelas ma WHERE
  ma.id NOT IN (SELECT ma_id from modelbs where modelbs.updated_at is null)
```

**Model A:**

```
public function modelb(){
return $this->hasMany('App\Modelb');
}
```

**Model B**

```
public function modela(){
return $this->belongsTo('App\Modela');
}
```

Now, I want to query all models A that have a model B where a certain column of model B ISN'T null.

**Here's how i tried:**

```
Modela::whereHas('modelbs', function ($query) {
            $query->whereNotNull('myColumnOfModelB');
        })->get();
```

This gave me exactly the records I wanted to exclude from my select

Comment: Apart from some inconsistencies (your relationship is `modelb`, but you're calling `whereHas('modelbs')` and a syntax error (you have 2 `))` at the end), this seems correct. Are you sure your relationships work as you intend them to?

Comment: I called it modelbs because eloquent pluralizes every table name. The relationships are working fine. I actually found out where I was mistaken. I will answer my own question with the right query.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I was able to find out where I was mistaken. So here is a query that achieves that raw sql:

```
Modela::whereDoesntHave('modelbs', function ($query) {
            $query->whereNull('someModelBcolumn');
        })->get()
```

**Raw SQL**

```
SELECT 
FROM modelas ma WHERE
  ma.id NOT IN (SELECT ma_id from modelbs where modelbs.updated_at is null)
```

The **"whereDoesntHave()"** is equivalent to "SELECT FROM modelas ma WHERE ma.id **NOT IN**" whereas the **"$query->whereNull()"** is the actual subquery equivalent to "(SELECT ma_id from modelbs where modelbs.updated_at **IS NULL**)"